# first parameter in memset passing array or pointer

Tags: c, memset

gcc 4.4.4 c89

Pointers are not the same as arrays. But arrays can decay into pointers.

I was just using memset which first parameter is a pointer. I would like to initialize my structure array.

i.e.

```
struct devices
{
    char name[STRING_SIZE];
    size_t profile;
    char catagory;
};

struct devices dev[NUM_DEVICES];

memset(dev, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(*dev));
```

dev == &dev[0]

But should I pass the first parameter has this:

```
 memset(&dev, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(*dev));
```

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: I know that this isn't exactly your question, but if you just do this to iniitialize your array of `struct` you should really just use something like the following `struct devices dev[NUM_DEVICES] = { { 0 } };` or even better if you have C99 `{ { .name = "" }}` on the right hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have:

```
memset(dev, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(*dev));
```

is fine - you pass a pointer to the first element of the array, and the size of the array.  However, the `(size_t)` cast is unnecessary (`sizeof` has type `size_t`, so it will cause the correct promotion) and I find that `dev[0]` is clearer than `*dev` in this case:

```
memset(dev, 0, NUM_DEVICES * sizeof dev[0]);
```

Alternatively, you *can* use `&dev` as the address.  In this case, it is probably clearer to use `sizeof dev` - the size of the whole array:

```
memset(&dev, 0, sizeof dev);
```

I say that this is clearer, because it's generally best to have the first parameter be a pointer to the type that's the subject of `sizeof` in the last parameter: the `memset()` should look like one of these forms:

```
memset(p, ..., N * sizeof p[0])
memset(&x, ..., sizeof x)
```

Note however that this last one only works if `dev` really is an array - like it is in this case.  If instead you have a pointer to the first element of the array, you'll need to use the first version.

Comment: `sizeof x` returns number of array elements only if array was allocated statically. Am I right?

Comment: @DanSkeel: It doesn't have anything to do with static storage duration - `sizeof a` will be the size of the array `a` as long as `a` is actually an array (and has complete type; it's an error to apply `sizeof` to something with incomplete type).  Note that pointers are *not* arrays, and applying `sizeof` to a pointer will give you the size of the pointer.  Note also that the size of an array is not necessarily the number of elements, it's the number of elements multiplied by the size of each element.

Comment: @caf: Maybe I used a wrong word... By statically I meant allocated on stack. I'm sorry to ask probably obvious thing, but I can't come up with a way to define array variable (not pointer) without setting it's size. So my point is that you can't use `sizeof` for getting size of dynamically allocated array. Or I miss something? Can you provide example if I'm wrong?

Comment: @DanSkeel: How the array is allocated isn't important - the important point is that `sizeof` will only tell you a size that is part of the *type*.  So you could have a dynamically allocated array like `int (*a)[100] = malloc(sizeof *a);` where `sizeof *a` correctly returns the size of the array `*a`.

Comment: Ok, you are right, we can allocate memory on a heap for array of predefined size. But by "dynamically" I meant to allocate array of size that is contained in a variable. If we allocate variable amount of memory we can't define a variable that is _array_, right? We will have to use pointer, and it will have "incomplete" type that we won't be able to use with `sizeof`, and will get only size of pointer or size of single element. Too many comments... If you have time I would love to clarify it in chat, thanks. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71457/clarification-of-sizeof-in-c

Comment: @DanSkeel: There's variably modified types: you can do `int (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof *a)` and `sizeof *a` will give the correct size (the value of `n` at the point of the declaration).

Comment: Your example doesn't compile. Can you provide compilable example? We should cast some type. Which?

Comment: @DanSkeel: `int (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof *a);` compiles fine as long as `n` is an integer in scope.  Variably-modified types were new in C99 so you might just have a really old C compiler.

Comment: @caf: Oh, my file was `.cpp` and I tried to compile it with `g++`. So this is a C feature [that is not included in C++?](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/dont-be-afraid-of-variably-modified-types/#comment-1526). It finally worked with `gcc`. Thank you for your time.